# Java Binary InOrder Tree Traversal - why does this initializing the ArrayList outside of the function make a difference?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

I wrote a recursive function to add all nodes of a binary tree into a list of type integer but it kept giving me problems for some reason. This is what my code initially looked like:

```
public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    helper(root, res);
    return res;
}

public void helper(TreeNode root, List<Integer> res){
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }
    inorderTraversal(root.left);
    res.add(root.val);
    inorderTraversal(root.right);
}
```

However it kept failing and not giving me proper solution. But it turns out that this code works if a take the first line out of the "inorderTraversal" function and made it global :

```
List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
```

Can someone explain to me why that makes a difference and why it was initially failing?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling 'inorderTraversal' recursively, every time that method is called, it overwrites 'res' and creates a new object. So, 'res' must be global to prevent this overwriting from happening.

Comment: but aren't I calling the helper recursively ? and not the "inorderTraversal" function?

Comment: Technically, neither of these functions are recursive, as they don't call themselves. But when you add the root.val to res, you then call inOrderTraversal again, which creates a new object. Take a look at [https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2112/2018fa/lectures/lecture.html?id=trees]

Answer (score 0):

i too encountered with same problem, the problem is that you are using recursion on inorderTraversal(). you should use recursion on helper method itself because what the helper method does it reflects on inorderTraversal(). code as follows.

```
public void helper(TreeNode root, List<Integer> ans){
        if(root != null){
            helper(root.left, ans);
            ans.add(root.data);
            helper(root.right, ans);
        }
    }
```